# Cut rectangle out of image after applying several transformations

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

I want to cut a renctangular shape out of an image.
I know the position of the rectangle relative to the orginal image.
However: When I rotate/scale/translate the image, the image dimensions changes. So my crop to the rectangle does not work anymore.

Is there a way to preserve the "old" coordinate system while transforming the image and then do a crop based on that old system?

The Image is always rotated/scaled around its center. Translation is applied after scaling and rotation.

I aim for a solution in php with imagick. However: When its not possible I am fine with command line imagemagick, too

Comment: A sample input and output image with and without the transformations marked up would help a lot...

Comment: Check out this [Stackoverflow Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/5494/transformations) to see how a transformation matrix can help you find your rotated, scaled, translated rectangle. The documentation is on the Html5-Canvas tag, but the matrix math applies universally.